# How to run project in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am getting

```
Internal Server Error
```

When I try to run laravel project. I think it's because it doesn't call the laravel public first.

How can i change it?

Comment: Please provide more information! Check out the log at `/storage/logs/laravel.log`. Have you set your permissions correctly?

Comment: I don't have that file